Can an AD Object with deny all permissions for Authenticated Users be recovered?
I have an Active Directory user where Security permissions were set to Deny all for the Authenticated Users principal.
That object now can't be read, such that the type is now Unknown instead of User.
Is there a way to recover this object by changing the permissions?
As far as I'm aware, there is no user or group that has explicit Allow permissions on that object.
Will communicating  directly to LDAP allow circumventing AD permissions?
Any pointers or experiences are welcome.
Thanks.


Is there a way to recover this object by maybe rectifying the permissions?

From what I know, the standard Windows process also works for AD objects:

As a Domain Admin, take ownership of the object.

As the object's owner, set new ACLs on the object.


It seems that "AD Users & Computers" offers this option, but dsacls /takeOwnership would be the next thing I'd be trying.
When testing this against Samba AD (as I don't have "real" AD at hand), on an object owned by the Domain Admins group, I saw that I could still read and modify the object's ACL when connected as a Domain Admin – i.e. I could just open the "unknown" object's Security tab, then uncheck 'Deny'.
If the object was owned by someone else, the Security tab didn't show me ACLs, but did offer me to set a new owner; setting it to 'Domain Admins' allowed me to modify the ACLs.

As far as I'm aware, there is no user or group that has explicit Allow permissions on that object.

That would still be useless if there were, as explicit Deny always takes precedence over Allow.

I was thinking of talking directly to LDAP in order to circumvent AD permissions entirely. Is that possible?

No. In your situation, "LDAP" and "AD" are one and the same: there is no separate "AD" proxy layer; you are already talking to the LDAP server, which is the one enforcing object permissions.
(Unless you meant directly accessing the database files, but that's not going to happen; there are no tools that I know of for directly modifying NTDS.DIT even if the DC allowed you to access it.)

Not really suggesting this, but I think it will work.
If you created a new Domain Administrator and jumped through the hoops to ensure it could be created without a password (potentially a lot of hoops), it would likely have an appropriate Allow permission, and would also NOT be a member of the obtain the Authenticated Users special identity group.
Edit: Just realized - you should also be able to start a process as SYSTEM, and use your tool of choice to un-bork the ACL.
--
Why is the object not inheriting permissions from a parent?  You should be able to force those down from a parent.
Also, if the object is subject to the SDProp process (adminCount=1), then update the ACL on the AdminSDHolder object.  If it is a protected account, and you just updated the ACL on the object (and not AdminSDHolder), then just wait for SDProp to run -- which should be hourly) and the ACL should reset.
